# Increase of component's height due to soldering

Tags: pcb, soldering

What is the increase of a two-terminal component's height after it has been soldered to a PCB in comparison to its height in an unsoldered state? Any rules of thumb?

I am interested in both reflow and hand soldering.

To understand what the question is look at the picture below:

[image]
[picture source](http://www.mtarr.co.uk/courses/ami4812_map2/restricted/u08/fsj/index.asp)

There is some extra height added to the component's height relative to the PCB's surface due to solder *under* the component.

My current understanding is that during reflow soldering nearly all solder fillet is extruded from beneath the component (to the so-called areas of toe, heel and sides), [video link](https://youtu.be/1G7HH3icagE). However, there are several hundreds (or maybe tens) microns of solder left beneath the component. If hand soldered, the increase could be greater than if reflow soldered, I guess (due to a greater amount of solder left under the component).

I am going to put several bypass capacitors beneath a chip socket (there are several areas where components lower than 0.5 mm or 1.1 mm are allowed). Thus, I need to be precise.

Comment: It's going to depend on a lot of factors, including pad size, stencil thickness, type of solder paste, etc. I don't think there is a good way to estimate it accurately.

Comment: @DerStrom8 10x. I guess/hope, adding 0.2 mm safety margin to a component's maximum nominal height (including manufacturing tolerance) should be enough.

Comment: Laser cut 0.13mm stencil thickness is common, hand soldering is uncontrolled

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 10x, pal.

Comment: 603 caps may be (0.76±0.25mm)

Comment: not even ok if you  use 402 caps 0.6mm max h

Comment: Some 402 caps are 0.5mm+/-0.05 so you need to consider 201 caps. forget about hand soldering these.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 tnx. I am using LLL153C80J224ME14 with 0.3+0.05 mm height (0204 low-esl bycap). Not sure whether I can put it in 0.5 mm allowed area, but, they should be fine in 1 mm allowed height area (there are actually two allowed areas, I didn't mention it in the question).

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 agreed, no hand soldering. it will be reflow.

Comment: A typical 125 micron stencil will leave a residual solder height (assuming that the stencil aperture and pad are the same size) of about 70 microns for a normal reflow process. The formula is aperture / pad area * 0.55 (for most solder pastes).

Comment: As long as no partial tombstone. ok. mechanical layout, pads, solder process and substrate design are all critical

Comment: @PeterSmith thank you. So, 70 microns of solder before heating should be further reduced to a fraction of it after heating, as I see. I didn't get how your formula works: if an aperture is a square of side d and pad area is the same size, then it is d/d^2*0.55? What units, mm or microns?

Comment: What would be height of the solder will be there in the pad after reflow , stencil thickness will be 6mil

Comment: @Renuka.G Read Sergei's answer - it answers your query .

Comment: A good answer would quote the relevant IPC standard though, rather than "John Doe told me...". There will very likely be a rule for this somewhere in those standards. I got curious and tried to dig up the relevant section, but no success.

Answer (score 6):

I contacted my foundry (over e-mail and phone).

They said:

1) They use stencils of four heights: 80 um, 100 um, 127 um and 150 um. **Standard (typical) stencil is of 127 um height.**

2) **Height of solder paste** after application of a stencil (before heating) **cannot be greater than height of stencil.**

*My comment:* I don't remember for sure, but I think they meant, that average height of solder paste is *equal* (not just not greater) to height of stencil.

3) **After heating (reflow) component *descends*.**

---

So, I conclude:

The height of component after reflow soldering is smaller than nominal (datasheet) component's height plus height of stencil. Or, in other words, the  **ceiling value for component's height after reflow soldering is component's nominal height before soldering + stencil height.**

PS1: I looked at several hand soldered capacitors. I do agree (with comments to the question) that the increase in case of hand soldering is uncontrollable. The additional height due to relatively large solder fillets under and above capacitors was as much as 0.5-0.6 mm (measured with eye).

PS2: Unfortunately, I don't have any reliable estimates how much the component descends after heating.

PS3: As soon as the PCB is produced and components are reflow mounted, I plan to update here about the resulting height and the socket.

Comment: I know this was four years ago, but did you ever take measurements of the remaining solder thickness after reflow? I have a similar situation now and any data you have would be really useful. Thanks!